# Proving the intersection and union of two open sets are open in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I am looking for a proof online that shows that $V\cap U$ and $V\cup U$ are open sets considering $V$ and $U$ are open while $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

I have the definition for an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ where $r(z) > 0$, $z \in U$ such that for any $w \in \mathbb{C}$:

$|w − z| < r(z) ⇒ w ∈ U$

Can anyone start me off or give a hint? A geometric approach would also be great.
Much appreciated.

Comment: You ask about the *intersection* and the *union* of two open sets.  A little investigation on your part will shed light on which of these is easier to prove is open, and the more you share your approach, the easier it will be for Readers to direct you around the difficulty you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $z \in V\cap U$ you have $r_1 >0$ and $r_2 >0$ as you use in the definition of open. Use $r:=min(r_1,r_2)$

if $z \in V\cup U$ it is even more trivial. You already know that there is a small disk contained in U (or V) containing z and hence contained in the union.